# Insert in unordered map calls constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, containers, destructor, rvalue

In order to avoid duplication of elements, I'm building a class that holds elements and provide an acces to them.

My elements (`DynLibrary`) are movable but not copyable

```
class DynLibrary
{
    public:
        DynLibrary() : _handle(nullptr) {}
        DynLibrary(const std::string& path) { DynLibrary::open(path); }
        DynLibrary(const DynLibrary&) = delete;
        DynLibrary(DynLibrary&&) = default;
        ~DynLibrary() { DynLibrary::close(); }
    ...
}
```

Those object are allocated in an `unordered_map` which key is the path that generated them.
I'm allocation them that way

```
class DynAllocator
{
    public:
        DynLibrary& library(const std::string& f)
        {
            if (_handles.find(f) == _handles.end())
            {
                std::cout << "@Emplace" << std::endl;
                _handles.emplace(f, DynLibrary(f));
            }
            std::cout << "@Return" << std::endl;
            return _handles.at(f);
        }
    private:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, DynLibrary> _handles;
};
```

However when calling `DynAllocator::library` I get the following output:

```
@Emplace
close 0x1dfd1e0 // DynLibrary destructor
@Return
```

Which means that the object which is inserted has somehow been copied and the destructor of the copy just invalidated my object (calling `dlclose` with my handler)

- Is my movable but not copyable approach of `DynLibrary` ok ?
- How can I insert an instance of `DynLibrary` if my `unordered_map` without copy ?

Please note that I know how to do that using pointers / smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`) but that i'd like to avoid them at all cost !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which means that the object which is inserted has somehow been copied and the destructor of the copy just invalidated my object

No, that's not what that means. `DynLibrary` has a `delete`d copy constructor, so the code would not compile if that constructor were somehow chosen through overload resolution.

```
_handles.emplace(f, DynLibrary(f));
```

What's happening on the line above is you're creating a temporary `DynLibrary` object which is then *move constructed* into the `unordered_map`. If you wish to avoid this move construction, use [`std::piecewise_construct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct_t) instead.

```
_handles.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                 std::forward_as_tuple(f),
                 std::forward_as_tuple(f));
```

Now you're directly constructing the `DynLibrary` object within the `unordered_map` and bypassing creation of the temporary.

---

As T.C. [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927882/insert-in-unordered-map-calls-constructor/29928143?noredirect=1#comment47978768_29928143), the piecewise construction constructor is not necessary in this case because `DynLibrary` has a non-`explicit` converting constructor. You can achieve the same effect as above with

```
_handles.emplace(f, f);
```

Comment: Thank you, then std::piecewise_construct approch works well. Still I'm wondering why would anyone want to call the destructor is called on the temporary ?

Comment: @Amxx: If you have a unique ownership resource, you're supposed to make the moved-from object not destroy the resource in it's destructor.

Comment: @Amxx You constructed a temporary which was then used as the source object for a move construction within the `unordered_map`. Once that's complete, the temporary needs to be destroyed, regardless of whether it was moved from or not.

Comment: @Amxx Puppy has a very good point in his comment. Depending on what type the `_handle` data member is, the defaulted move constructor may not be sufficient. For instance, if it is a `void *`, you'll need to define the move constructor and set the source object's `_handle` to `nullptr` to avoid it being destroyed in the destructor of the source object.

Comment: Do you actually need `piecewise_construct` for the the code shown in the OP? The `pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );` constructor should handle it. (Of course, if `DynLibrary(const std::string& path)` were `explicit`, you'd need it...)

Comment: @Praetorian that exactly what happened. `DynLibrary` contains a `void* _handle` which was copied from the temporary but not set to `nullptr` so destroying the temporary was making the handle invalid

Comment: @T.C. I tried using `_handles.emplace(f, std::move(DynLibrary(f)));` but that didn't work

Comment: @Praetorian, Thx, I don't undestand how I can have missed such a simple solution. At least I would have learn the existence of `std::piecewise_construct`