# C++: How can I pass keys and values into a constructor to make a map without copying the values of the map during construction?

Tags: c++, copy, copy-constructor, move-semantics

Here is a minimal example where an object of type `WrapMap` contains an `unordered_map`. The only thing that will change in the map is the values, not the length and not the keys.

However, I have found that each value passed into each pair is copied twice.
By using `move`, it seems to have reduced the number of copies by 1 (although the move doesn't show up in the output, so maybe I've done something wrong).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using std::cout;

struct MyStruct {
    int x;
    MyStruct(int x) : x(x) { cout << "Constructed " << this << " from " << x << "\n"; }
    MyStruct(const MyStruct& from) : x(from.x) { cout << "Copied      " << this << " from " << &from << "\n"; }
    MyStruct(MyStruct&& from) : x(from.x) { cout << "Moved       " << this << " from " << &from << "\n"; }
    ~MyStruct() { cout << "Destructed  " << this << " from " << x << "\n"; }
};

struct WrapMap {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, MyStruct>&& my_map;
    WrapMap(std::unordered_map<std::string, MyStruct>&& kv)
        : my_map(std::move(kv)) {
        /*
        // Just to make sure it inputs the values correctly
        cout << "{";
        for (auto it = my_map.begin(); it != my_map.end(); ++it) {
            if (it != my_map.begin()) cout << ", ";
            cout << it->first << ": MyStruct " << it->second.x;
        }
        cout << "}\n";
        */
    }
};

int main() {
    WrapMap object({
        {"foo", 2},
        // several pairs
    });
}
```

```
Constructed 0x7ffd76fadbb8 from 2                                                                                               
Copied      0x2611c80 from 0x7ffd76fadbb8                                                                                       
{foo: MyStruct 2}                                                                                                               
Destructed  0x7ffd76fadbb8 from 2                                                                                               
Destructed  0x2611c80 from 2
```

My assumption is that the long pointer points to const memory (just a guess) and so it has to copy each element from const memory to non-const memory.

I have attempted to use an `initializer_list<pair<string, MyStruct>>` but I couldn't convert it to an `unordered_map`.

`std::unordered_map<std::string, MyStruct> object = { {"foo", 2} }` calls the copy constructor for each value, it seems.

How can I make it so that each key is never copied (or at least minimise it?)

Related: [Insert in unordered map calls constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927882/insert-in-unordered-map-calls-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### emplace

You can use the [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) member function of `unordered_map`:

> Inserts a new element into the container constructed in-place with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container.
>
> Careful use of emplace allows the new element to be constructed while avoiding unnecessary copy or move operations. The constructor of the new element (i.e. `std::pair<const Key, T>`) is called with exactly the same arguments as supplied to emplace, forwarded via `std::forward<Args>(args)...`. [...]

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, MyStruct> m;
m.emplace(std::make_pair("foo", 2));
```

#### C++17: try_emplace

As of C++17, you can also make use of [`try_emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/try_emplace) which allows retaining a given resource passed to it if the key already exists:

> [...] Unlike `insert` or `emplace`, these functions **do not move from rvalue arguments if the insertion does not happen**, which makes it easy to manipulate maps whose values are move-only types, such as `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<foo>>`. In addition, `try_emplace` treats the key and the arguments to the mapped_type separately, unlike `emplace,` which requires the arguments to construct a `value_type` (that is, a `std::pair`) [...].

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, MyStruct> m;
m.try_emplace("foo", 2);
```

Comment: It seems quite cumbersome for many pairs and several maps, but it works perfectly! +1